# How to solve error when using xcorr to find time delay between two sinus 10Hz

Tags: matlab

I have a problem when I have tried to implement `xcorr` (MATLAB) to find a time delayed between 2 signals: `x = cos(2*pi*10*t)` and `y = cos(2*pi*10*t + pi)`

Here is my results after implementing `xcorr` MATLAB. I don't understand how to remove high spikes in the graphic of time delay. Does anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

[image: 2 raw signals 10Hz]
[image: Time shift after xcorr MATLAB]

Comment: What do you mean with implementing `xcorr` in MATLAB? It is a builtin function. What is your definition of `t`?

Answer (score 3):

Using the following definition for your signal:

```
dt = 0.01;
t = 0:dt:1;
x = cos(2*pi*10*t);
y = cos(2*pi*10*t + pi);
```

You can calculate the time delay as follows using `xcorr`:

```
[C, LAGS] = xcorr(x, y);
[~, i] = max(C);
time_lag = dt * LAGS(i) % returns -0.05 (i.e. 50ms delay)
```

The cross correlation should look as follows (`plot(C)`):

[image]